# Why do we use the baseUrl in Selenium

Tags: selenium

Every Selenium test script I see always use a baseUrl string when opening new instances of the driver (usually present in the @Before or @BeforeClass annotations).

What is the reasoning behind this? Is there any sort of advantages over just having the entire url in the `.get()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the baseUrl is just a way to represent where you are wanting to go. The reason they probably use it in a variable is so you can build off of it in your tests.

Lets say you have multiple environments you want to run your test on:

```
www.qa.example.com
www.dev.example.com 
www.example.com
```

Instead of changing this every where you typed the webaddress you change the one variable labeled baseUrl once and it updates all your tests.